# Ruby boolean logic: some amount of variables are true

Tags: ruby

Let say I have 3 variables: `a`, `b`, `c`.

How can I check that just zero or one of them is true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[a, b, c].count(true) < 2
```

.....................

Comment: same idea :  `[a, b, c].count(true) <= 1`